# Where has Baldur's Gate II GOG version been installed to?

Tags: wine, games

I downloaded the linux version of Baldur's Gate II from GOG.com, and made the sh-file executable (`sudo chmod +x gog_baldur...`). I then ran the script and installed the game to my home directory: `/home/myusername/GOG Games/Baldurs Gate 2 Complete`.

2 icons got created on my desktop, which call the `start.sh` from inside the install directory. The game starts just fine, so the installation was successful.

I tried figuring out where the acutal game files are located as I would like to install some mods, too. However, they are not in my home directory and I can't seem to find the directory mentioned in the `start.sh`, which would be `drive_c/GOG Games/Baldur's Gate 2/`.

However, if I navigate to `/home/myusername/.wine/drive_c/GOG Games/` the Baldur's Gate 2 directory is nowhere to be found. There are other GOG games I installed, but not BG2. So... where are the game files actually located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have no idea where the files would be exactly, I suggest searching for them. It is reasonable to assume, that the any folder containing the files would contain `baldur`. So you can open a terminal and execute

```
find . -iname "*baldur*"
```

To try and locate those folders/files. Or if you know a more specific filename you can search for that

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped a lot. I searched for "bgmain.exe" and found it within the original folder, within the subfolder "prefix".